# Unexpected R dataframe problem

Tags: r

I have a long list of dates that i want to parse, they are in a dataframe (`the_dates`). I've loaded them into R (from a sqlite db) just fine, however, if i do `str(the_dates)` i get:

```
'data.frame':   3968 obs. of  1 variable:
```

somehow R treats this as a single variable, which is why i am having trouble converting into Date format - i found a workaround:

```
as.Date(the_dates[1:3968,], "%B %d, %Y")
```

This works, but is obviously not optimal because I have to lookup the length manually (`length(the_dates)` returns `1`) -- any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's see the head() of your data.frame. 1 variable (in length) means one column. Can you show us the rest of the commands you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right.  You have only "one variable" (i.e. column) in your data.frame.  A column is a "variable" and a row is an "observation".

Try this:

```
as.Date(the_dates[,1], "%B %d, %Y")
```

The "length" of a data.frame comes from `nrow`, not `length`.

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:20)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> length(df)
[1] 1
> nrow(df)
[1] 20
```

I recommend reading ["An Introduction to R"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html).